# How to add values from two dataframes according to the persons in first column? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, addition

I have two dataframes

```
df1

    Name    2010  2011
0   Jack     25    35
1   Jill     15    20

df2

    Name    2010  2011
0   Berry    45    25
1   Jack     5     10
```

I want to create a third dataframe by adding the values in these dataframes

`Desired Output`

```
df3

    Name    2010  2011
0   Jack     30    45      #add the values from df1 and df2
1   Jill     15    20
2   Berry    45    25
```

I have used this code
`df1.add(df2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concat` both dfs and do a `groupby` and `sum`:

```
print (pd.concat([df, df2]).groupby("Name", as_index=False).sum())

    Name  2010  2011
0  Berry    45    25
1   Jack    30    45
2   Jill    15    20
```